# Laravel Telescope missing records

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am using Laravel telescope for monitoring jobs but it seems that Telescope do not monitor all jobs. Example: There are more than 500 jobs executed in 2 minutes but Telescope just 10 jobs executed like minutes ago.

Same issue for other watchers